# Different image output with same inversed transformation

Tags: python-3.x, image, transformation, scikit-image

I got different image output while transformation stayed the same

```
im=np.ones((128,128))*255
src = np.array([
    [56., 60.],
    [81., 60.],
    [64., 80.],
    [49., 100.],
    [78., 100.]], dtype=np.float32)
q=np.array([
    [58.166317,39.124466],
    [86.10652,26.917824],
    [106.29474,39.68392],
    [90.64203,72.82854],
    [115.17699,63.91104]],dtype=np.float32)
tt=trans.SimilarityTransform()
tt.estimate(q,src)
dst1 = trans.warp(im,tt.inverse,preserve_range=True,output_shape=(128,128))
tt.estimate(src,q)
dst = trans.warp(im,tt,preserve_range=True,output_shape=(128,128))
```

So,you can see the difference, here are outputs:

[image: dst1]
[image: dst]
Why are not they the same?

UPD:
Main issue is in "estimate" function, that estimate(q,src)!=(estimate(src,q))^-1. Still open question: why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify the question: affine transformations is a group of transformations `t:R2->R2`, where you have one determined inverse element for each (in our case - inverse transformation). In my question it appears that we have *different* transformations to the same source points (two inverse elements).
Actually, there is no mistake anywhere, just misunderstanding `.inverse` and `.estimate` function. `t.estimate(q, src).inverse !=t.estimate(src, q)` but `t.estimate(q, src).inverse ==t.estimate(t(q),q)`